# Peculiar result from observable: testing with Jasmine marbles

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, jestjs, jasmine-marbles

I have a little function in Angular 7 that I am testing with Jest. The function looks like this:

```js
private checkFreeProduct(allowance: SubscriberConnectivityAllowanceInterface): Observable<SubscriberConnectivityAllowanceInterface> {

    // TODO: This is currently just a temp function to be extended when required
    return of(allowance);

}
```

As you can see, for the moment all it is doing is creating an observable from its input, but it is under development and will be extended.

I am testing it with Jest like this:

```js
it('should return an observable of the allowance', () => {

    const allowance: SubscriberConnectivityAllowanceInterface = {
        hotspotAuthenticated: HotspotAuthenticationEnum.TRUE,
        remainingOctets: 100,
        remainingSeconds: 200,
        activeProductCost: ConnectivityProductCostEnum.PAID,
        activeProductDuration: ConnectivityProductDurationEnum.FLIGHT,
        activeProductType: ConnectivityProductTypeEnum.PREMIUM,
        connectivityProducts: []
    };

    const expected = hot('a|', {
        a: allowance
    });

    expect(hotspotService['checkFreeProduct'](allowance)).toBeObservable(expected);

});
```

However, the test is failing because of some timing issue. The `expected` observable result looks like this:

```js
[
  {
    "frame": 0,
    "notification": {
      "error": undefined,
      "hasValue": true,
      "kind": "N",
      "value": {
        "activeProductCost": "paid",
        "activeProductDuration": "flight",
        "activeProductType": "premium",
        "connectivityProducts": [],
        "hotspotAuthenticated": 1,
        "remainingOctets": 100,
        "remainingSeconds": 200
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "frame": 10,
    "notification": {
      "error": undefined,
      "hasValue": false,
      "kind": "C",
      "value": undefined
    }
  }
]
```

and the observable created from the function call `hotspotService['checkFreeProduct'](allowance)` looks like this:

```js
[
  {
    "frame": 0,
    "notification": {
      "error": undefined,
      "hasValue": true,
      "kind": "N",
      "value": {
        "activeProductCost": "paid",
        "activeProductDuration": "flight",
        "activeProductType": "premium",
        "connectivityProducts": [],
        "hotspotAuthenticated": 1,
        "remainingOctets": 100,
        "remainingSeconds": 200
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "frame": 0, // <------- this is the only difference
    "notification": {
      "error": undefined,
      "hasValue": false,
      "kind": "C",
      "value": undefined
    }
  }
]
```

Now I'm not exactly sure why there are two emissions from these observables, but I'll go with it. What I don't understand is why the observable from the function call emits two events, both on frame 0. I have tried both `hot()` and `cold()`, and have experimented with various marbles in these calls but no joy. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Its almost 2 yrs on this post, but still can you accept my response as the answer if it helped you so that someone who comes to this post knows there is a solution for this question . Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The question you asked about two events emitted is because of the marble `hot('a|')` - 1st one is emitting the value that you wish to assert 'a' and second is emitted to indicate the completion of the hot observable `'|'`. This can be inferred from the Notification -> Kind property in those events that you have added in your question. Ex: "kind": "N" -> Value emitted. kind": "C" -> completion of observable.

**Answer**:
To fix your unit test, just change the marble to `'(a|)'`, so that both of them are emitted in the same time frame. I have tested this and it works.

**Reason for different time frames:**
The hot and cold create observable streams that emit values on specific time intervals. Marbles denote actions that happen over time on observables.

- `-` - denotes a unit of time frame.
- `[a-z0-9]` - denotes values emitted from stream.
- `|` - denotes completion of observable stream.
- `#` - denotes error in observable stream.
- `()` - denotes grouping of values emitted on the same time frame.

*For your solution*, `hot('(a|'))` - means emit both the value `a` and complete the observable stream within the same time frame.

**References:**
https://github.com/jisaacks/RxJS/blob/master/doc/writing-marble-tests.md 
https://medium.com/@bencabanes/marble-testing-observable-introduction-1f5ad39231c

Comment: *As you can see, for the moment all it is doing is creating an observable from its input, but it is under development and will be extended*

Comment: ok. I just wanted to give an alternate way to test the service. I have updated my answer

Comment: This is getting there but needs to be better explained. For a start, I'd move your Answer to the top and work from that, not as a footnote

Comment: Added some explanation and links.

Comment: I've edited your answer to show what I mean, feel free to undo but that's what I'd do, the first bit is irrelevant to the actual question getting asked

Comment: Got it. The 1st bit was something that was to be removed but i didnt. But the marbles should have helped you to move ahead with your unit test.

Comment: @Liam: Its almost 2 yrs on this post, but still can you accept my response as the answer if it helped you so that someone who comes to this post knows there is a solution for this question . Thanks.

Comment: this isn't my question